# Element wise subtraction of a vector?

Tags: r

I have the following vector in R

```
x<-c(5,7,8,20,11,30)
```

I want to get all the possible subtractions `xi-xj`, `1<=i<j<=6`. I used `outer` function but I got a matrix with zero diagonal. I do not want to have `xi-xj` with `i=j`. Additionally, I want to have a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: Flatten the matrix: `as.vector(outer(x,x,'-'))` or `c(outer(x,x,'-'))`.

Comment: `outer` is not the right solution, see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63558868/element-wise-substraction-of-a-vector-in-r#comment112391261_63558925)  to user @RonalShah's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63558925/8245406).

Answer (score 4):

You can subset the output of `outer` using `lower.tri` or `upper.tri`.

```
y <- outer(x, x, '-')
y[lower.tri(y)]
# [1]  2  3 15  6 25  1 13  4 23 12  3 22 -9 10 19
```

Alternatively you can generate the indices using `seq` and `rep`.

```
k <- seq(length(x) - 1, 1)
i <- rep(seq_along(k), k)
j <- sequence(k) + i
x[j] - x[i]
# [1]  2  3 15  6 25  1 13  4 23 12  3 22 -9 10 19
```

Comment: nice solution with `lower.tri`, +1. A one-liner option `outer(x,x,"-")[lower.tri(diag(x))]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `outer` generates a matrix with all possible combinations in both the directions (`a - b` and `b - a`) which is unnecessary in this case.

Perhaps, you can use `combn` :

```
combn(x, 2, diff)
#[1]  2  3 15  6 25  1 13  4 23 12  3 22 -9 10 19
```

Also as @Rui Barradas points out that `outer` might not be the right solution since it fails for the condition `1<=i<j<=6`.

Comment: Maybe you could add that this is the right result, not `outer` since `outer` will also compute `x1-x1`, `x2-x2`, etc and the OP expressly asks for `xi-xj` with `1<=i<j<=6`. The indices must be different.

Answer (score 0):

Higher order functions; less succinct/readable than above but quicker for some reason.

```
Filter(function(y) {y != 0},
   do.call("c", (Map(function(i){y <- x - x[i]; y[i:length(x)]}, seq_along(x)))))
```

Comment: @Dharman a bit of both, I think its an interesting question that someone may have the answer to. It is faster than combn() and I don't understand why. I would have thought combn() would be optimal given this is what it's built in to R to do.

Comment: @Dharman no worries, didn't mean to stir the pot, just interested.